# How to escape this redirect loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make all a user's illicit attempts to see other users' **show** page redirect instead to their own **show** page.

None of my attempts in the **else** section of this code do the job though.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if params[:id] == current_user.id.to_s
      liked_bookmark_ids = current_user.likes.pluck(:bookmark_id)
      liked_bookmarks = Bookmark.where(id:liked_bookmark_ids)
      liked_topic_ids = liked_bookmarks.pluck(:topic_id)
      @liked_topics = Topic.where(id:liked_topic_ids).order('topics.name')
    else
      # redirect_to :controller => 'users', :id => current_user.id # gives a screwy url
      # redirect_to user_path, :id => 6                            # causes a redirect loop
      # redirect_to :back                                          # causes a redirect loop  
    end
  end
end
```

What's the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
redirect_to user_path(current_user)
```

Comment: You can probably even do `redirect_to(current_user)`... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to

Comment: well what do you know... couldn't be simpler - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach would be to use a [`filter`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) to check if it's a request by a current user or not. You can do something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_current_user, only: :show      

  def show
    liked_bookmark_ids = current_user.likes.pluck(:bookmark_id)
    liked_bookmarks = Bookmark.where(id:liked_bookmark_ids)
    liked_topic_ids = liked_bookmarks.pluck(:topic_id)
    @liked_topics = Topic.where(id:liked_topic_ids).order('topics.name')
  end

  private

  def check_current_user
    redirect_to current_user, notice: "Not authorized"  if params[:id] != current_user.id.to_s
  end
end
```